# Concrete5 - library not being loaded

Tags: php, concrete5

I'm trying to load a custom library in Concrete5.
I've created a library file, internallib.php, and placed the file in the /libraries folder.  This file does not extend any core library files.  I keep getting this error:

> Warning: require_once(/var/www/concrete/libraries/internalauth.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/portal/concrete/core/libraries/loader.php on line 30

Though if I move the file into the folder /concrete/libraries, I don't get this error.  Should I be putting my library file into the concrete/libraries, or /libraries folder?  I assumed that since this is a 3rd party library, it should go into the root libraries folder, as not to conflict with any future core updates.

I'm currently running v.5.6.0.2

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the root libraries folder is the place to go.
You could try to put it in libraries/3rdparty which is where 3rd party libraries should be.

The problem however might come from the way you are calling the library, not from the library itself.

Maybe you could tell us more?